# Update column value in Ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm loading the Grid in `Component A`. In `Component B` i'm modifying a value, that modified value should be reflected in `Component A`.

using `Subject` i can successfully get the modified value to `Component A` but the updated value is not getting displayed.

Please help me here i'm stuck with this issue.

Below is my Code

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  this.sessionWatch.transitDaysAvg.subscribe((newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
      // newValue is 6 Old value is 1
      var rowNode = this.gridOptions.api.getRowNode("0");
      rowNode.setDataValue("transitLink.businessDays", newValue);
      this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({
        force: true
      });

    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div role="row" row-index="0" comp-id="602">
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="753" col-id="transitLink.businessDays">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then your components should be in child-parent relationship, and you can use `@Input` and `@Output` to receive or emit values.

Comment: i'm already using Subject, i can able to access the child data in parent component. Only issue is to display the updated value in that particular column

Comment: Using `Subject` is kinda observable stuff, so you need to subscribe that observable, and in Observable, every time you need to call `next()` of observable to update value, which is good but requires more useless codes (for this case I say it useless), cuz angular has given us the `@Input` & `@Output` for child-parent interaction, it's easy and needs no extra stuff like `Subject` or  `Observable`.

Comment: yes, but my problem is to update the cell with new value. That's wer i'm facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No need to refresh the cells after setting the data value. The setDataValue itself updates the row data by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).